# Drawing smooth 2D curves with 2D spline in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

The problem I am running into here is the following: there is a set of 4 points in 2D, and I need to plot a smooth curve in 2D space that runs through these points. Is there a package in R to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [xspline](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/xspline.html) function offers a generalization of Catmull-Rom splines, which sounds like what you want. From the examples:

[image: xspline example]

Comment: "xspline"  is more cute.

Comment: Thank you that was it! Is there a way to retrieve the analytic form of the splines? The results just give me the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be treated as a polynomial interpolation problem. The following example might help you. You don't need extra package.

```
x <- c(1 : 4)
y <- rnorm(4)
plot(x, y)  # plot the four points.
lines(spline(x, y))  # plot the curve.
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a 2-D curve, which is not the same thing as a functional relationship.